# Animate click function with in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Everything works fine except the animate click function.

I would like to have the background to animate when clicked.
I know that i can do the div tag in html and call that, but it is not what i want.

Can anyone tel me how it can be done with in the script?

```
if (numbers[i] == 1){
    $('<div>1</div>').css({
            background: "url(img/1.png)", 
            'background-size': '100% 100%', 
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
        })
        .data( 'number', numbers[i] )
        .attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] )
        .appendTo( '#cardPile' + pile[i] ).draggable({
            containment: '#content',
            stack: '#cardPile1 div',
            cursor: 'move',
        })
        .click(function(){
            $('<div>1</div>').animate({
                height:'181px', 
                width:'169px', 
                top: '-30', 
                left: '-20', opacity: '0.4'
            }, 1000)
        });
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click your first div you create a second:

```
$('<div>1</div>').animate({....
```

Maybe you want to use the same in the animation?

```
$(this).animate({...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i was thinking the same, but it is a dragable puzzle and then you have to click twice to drag.

Comment: Sorry, yes it works thanks. i was tying the first option, second option works great :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `append` the div like this

```
$('<div>1</div>').animate({
      height:'181px',
      width:'169px',
      top: '-30', 
      left: '-20', 
      opacity: '0.4'}
   , 1000).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that dos not do the work, nothing happens.